# IntelliSense compile error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, razor, intellisense

I am trying to reference my model with `@model xxx.YYY` at the top of my razor view. I am getting this error:

> C:\xxx_yyy.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

`System.Web.Mvc` and `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` are included in my references and the code is compiling and running, however IntelliSense is not compiling my razor view, meaning I'm unable to access auto-complete etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you copy your web.config from both the app root and the `~/Views` directory? Chances are have a reference to the assembly and the version isn't matching.